# MS Access pass through query records sorted while getting the same data

Tags: database, oracle, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created an MS Access tool to get the data from Oracle tables through pass through query. I have created local tables for all the queried Oracle tables (Around 120 Tables from Oracle) and named as `Pre_[Oracle Table Name]`. And again I have queried all the Oracle tables and created local tables as `Post_[Oracle Table Name]`. The query which I used is very simple. `Select * into Pre_[Oracle Table Name] from [Pass through query (select * from [Oracle Table] where ID in ('20150201','20150202')]`. When I tried to compare pre and post tables in Ms Access through VBA, I found some of the tables are sorted even though its having same data. Could you anyone tell me why the data is getting sorted when we use the same pass through query? Is there anyway to rectify this?

Planning to change the VBA code which compare the Pre and post Tables. The below is the code. How do I change the code to compare the entire row of Pre is present in Post? The code should not restrict to columns because the columns will vary for all the tables.

```
    Set curDB = CurrentDb()
strSQL = "Select * from tbl_TABLE_LIST"
Set rsdfs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
With rsdfs
If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
.MoveLast
.MoveFirst
While (Not .EOF)
tblDFS = rsdfs.Fields("DFS_TABLE")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Pre_" & tblDFS
Set rs = curDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM Post_" & tblDFS
Set rs1 = curDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_DFS_TABLE_COMPARE_DATA"
Set rs2 = curDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
i = 1
Do Until rs.EOF
For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
Val1 = rs.Fields(x).Value
Val2 = rs1.Fields(x).Value
If Val1 <> Val2 Then
rs2.AddNew
rs2!DFS_TABLE = tblDFS
rs2!Pre_Tbl_Row_No = i
rs2!Pre_Tbl_Col_Name = rs.Fields(x).Name
rs2!Pre_Tbl_Col_Value = rs.Fields(x).Value
rs2!Post_Tbl_Row_No = i
rs2!Post_Tbl_Col_Name = rs1.Fields(x).Name
rs2!Post_Tbl_Col_Value = rs1.Fields(x).Value
rs2.Update
```

Comment: Try adding ORDER BY clauses to your queries to ensure that the rows are sorted the same way each time.

Comment: I dont have the Primary or Unique key information for all the tables to use Order by Clause. Also all the tables have different columns.

Comment: If you don't have an `ORDER BY`, the data is *not* sorted. It might look like it is, but that will just be a by-product of whatever query plan the database happened to use at the time.

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY 1, 2`  , where `1, 2` means result column1 , result coulmn2

Comment: The number of fields are differs from table to table. Also i dont have the Primary or Unique key information and their Order number for all the tables to use Order by Clause.

Comment: Any help for my query?